# How can I programmatically tell how many facets a ggplot has?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Below is code and a graph.

The graph has three facets.  Where in `the_plot` can I find it has three facets?  Yes, I could get that from the `mtcars` data frame, or `the_plot$data`, but I don't want to recreate the data analysis.  Rather, I want to inspect the graphical elements of `the_plot`, so I don't have to duplicate application logic in multiple places.  `the_plot$facet` doesn't show anything I recognize, nor do the other plot variables.

I'm using tidyverse 1.3.0.

```
library(tidyverse)
data(mtcars)
the_plot<-ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp, group=cyl)) + facet_wrap(~cyl) + geom_point()
the_plot
```

[image: faceted plot]

Comment: Possibly `ggplot_build(the_plot)$layout$layout` from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44107119/extract-number-of-rows-from-faceted-ggplot

Comment: Do add some details, your `the_plot` is not what you see in the plot, but a description of what you want to be plotted (data, mapping, theme, etc.). When you write `the_plot` in the console, you are really calling `print(the_plot)`, which starts a process that realises the scales, number and position of facets, etc. and then outputs boxes, lines and text to a graphical device.

Answer (score 13):

you can access the ggplot data with the gg_build() - function

```
out <- ggplot_build(the_plot)

length(levels(out$data[[1]]$PANEL))
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 9):

Another method

```r
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)
the_plot<-ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp, group=cyl)) + facet_wrap(~cyl) + geom_point()
pb <- ggplot_build(the_plot)
pb$layout$layout$PANEL
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> Levels: 1 2 3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>